# How to know which disk has failed on a Mirrored Raid? marked as DR0

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid

Our 2ndry DC, which is on a W2K8R2 Mirrored software raid has lost it's sync, and disk management displays the failed redundancy error

[image]

- How do I know which of the disks has failed? (beside to try and replace one - and see if it loads and syncs)

On the device manager, under disks I see both disks, one of them has an icon of: Disable, while the other doesn't

[image][image]

- Event log displays an event id 7 - bad block on Hard disk DR0

[image]

The thing is that looking in device manager, both disks are located in '0' location, which is bizzare

[image] [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From an elevated command prompt run `diskpart`. Once you're in diskpart, run `detail disk` and `detail volume` after selecting the appropriate disk/volume using the `select` command. This should list the health state of each disk.

Of course, in this case, the yellow caution symbol on disk 0 is probably a good indicator :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the disk management screen, `Disk 0` is displayed with a yellow warning icon, while `Disk 1` is not. I would hazard a guess that it was `Disk 0` which reported the bad blocks, but you might want to investigate that yourself before pulling drives.

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that one :-/  but still, yea, ill need to investigate - hopefully will pull the correct one

Comment: +1 Disk with Yellow Yield sign is the "bad" disk.