# Can't boot after Disk 0 of software raid is replaced

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid

On a windows 2008 R2, which was on a mirrored software raid, Disk 0 has failed.

After I replaced it with an alternate drive (can not find the same capacity and model) - the server isn't booting.  (it's an Intel SE7320VP2)

- If I push the bad drive in, I get the following options to boot:

  - Windows Server 2008 R2
  - Windows Server 2008 R2 Secondary Plex

[image]

- Theoretically, can the server boot with only 1 of the drives? (the good one that didn't fail)?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, so I'll leave this in a comment. Windows software RAID isn't transparent like hardware RAID or something like `mdadm`. In 2003, you used to have to put a boot floppy in and set boot.ini to boot from the second disk. In 2008 R2, I wouldn't be surprised if you had to fiddle with `bcdedit` or at least press `f8` during boot and select the other disk if it is available.

Comment: Are you sure it was a mirrored pair and not striped or a span?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this is the same server as in [this previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/438546/how-to-know-which-disk-has-failed-on-a-mirrored-raid-marked-as-dr0)?

In that question you posted this screenshot (Now slightly edited).
[image: Screenshot fo diskm management with failed stuff highlighted]

Notice three things:

1. You are not mirroring **drives** but only a **partition**  (C:)
2. Windows boots from a drive.
3. The drive with the system reserved partition (and bootcode) is the failed drive.

Comment: yes, it's the same server. Now added info on Plex to the question.

Comment: So to sum it up, the computer booted off Disk 0, the replacement has no System partition and Disk 1 has no System partition. This is what happens when a true disk mirror is not in place. You have to figure out how to take Disk 1 offline so you don't damage it, create a system partition on the replacement so it's bootable and then mount Disk 1 so you can back it up before reestablishing mirroring and for real disaster recovery, mirror the drives, not just the partitions.

Comment: I never used mirrored volumes on boot disks, so take all of this with a grain of salt. I see a few ways to solve this. 1) Add a third drive. Mirror the system reserved to it. Mirror C: to it. Replace failed drive 0 with the new drive. (Possibly add some BCDedit magic somewhere).   2) After checking that your backups work move the C: mirror from the second partition to the right. Then add a mirror of the System reserved. Test if booting works from drive 1. If it works swap drive 0 and boot (BIOS, hotkey F12?) from drive 1. Restore to the new empty drive 0.

Comment: [end of comment char limit] Option 3) remove both drive. Add new drives as drive 0. Install windows including boot stuff. Insert drive 1. Somehow mirror from drive 1 to drive 0.

Comment: A bit late, but I just discovered how your system probably got into the C-volume only mirred state:  See joseph_morris answer on http://superuser.com/questions/357051/how-can-i-mirror-a-drive-when-no-extents-are-found-for-plex

Answer (score 2):

Eventually what I did:

- Use a bare metal restore to a new drive
- Add a 2nd new drive, and create mirror's of both system and data disk.

LOVE SYSTEM BACKUPS !!