# Windows Server 2008 Software RAID with Different Size SSD's

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

I'm planning on buying an extra SSD to install into my server to do Software RAID1 in Windows Server 2008.

At this moment I have a Crucial M4 64GB SSD which is running fine, I would like to add a Crucial M500 120GB to it and use a 64GB partition for RAID1 and the other GBs for normal storage (for manual backups to be exact)

Is this possible? Or should I just go for another 64GB SSD and do RAID1 with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need identical sized **disks** to use then in RAID.
You can usually used identical sized **volumes/partitions** for software RAID.

However consider these points:

1. Not all RAID software might accept that.
2. Using a volume in a mirror only mirrors that volume. You probably also want to make sure that the boot sector (etc etc) also gets mirror, to avoid situations like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/438928/cant-boot-after-disk-0-of-software-raid-is-replaced) (Data was mirrored, but not the rest needed for booting the OS)
3. Backups on the same part as the mirror? Hopefully not backups from the mirror.
4. (Or rather 3b): The only good backup is an **off site, off-line** backup.

Having said all that: Yes, *technically* it is possible.

Comment: Thanks a ton, At this moment I'm backing up my MySQL database to an external host (server is in the netherlands, backup in France takes too long to backup 6GB with 20mb upload speed) I would like to do a RAID1 using the default windows mirroring features and use the other space for manual database backup looks like that might be a bad idea from your answer if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: Having RAID 1/mirroring is a great idea to guard against a single disk loss. However it is no replacement for a backup. A lightning strike, a fire, theft etc etc can still take out two disks at the same time, and no RAID format will help you with that.  RAID is great for some extra performance, or when you want to make sure that a server stays up until after office hours before doing emergency maintenance. In no way does RAID ever replace backups.

Answer (score 2):

Get another 64GB SSD... ideally another of the same. If you're planning for backup space, use another drive... possibly something external to the system. It's not much of a backup if it's part of the same RAID array.

Comment: Except he can backup over stuff there. I do somethign similar with 8 discs - 4 smaller, 5 larger. Raid over all 8, plus a Raid 5 over the larger 4. Nice 1.5tb for backing up the main database server - which lives on another machine.